# Finding table size (in MB/GB) in Spark SQL

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql, query-performance, aws-glue

First, please allow me to start by saying that I am pretty new to `Spark-SQL`.

I am trying to understand various Join types and strategies in Spark-Sql, I wish to be able to know about an approach to approximate the sizes of the tables (which are participating in a Join, aggregations etc) in order to estimate/tune the expected execution time by understanding what is really happening under the hood to help me to pick the Join strategy which is best suited for that scenario (in Spark-SQL through hints etc).

Of course, the table row-counts offers a good starting point, but I want to be able to estimate the sizes in terms of `bytes`/`KB`/`MB`/`GB`/`TB`s, to be cognizant which table would/would not fit in memory etc) which in turn would allow me to write more efficient SQL queries by choosing the Join type/strategy etc that is best suited for that scenario.

Note : I do not have access to PySpark. We query the Glue tables thru Sql Workbench connected to the Glue catalog with a Hive jdbc driver.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

see if this helps to find the size of table-

```scala
 /**
      * file content
      * spark-test-data.json
      * --------------------
      * {"id":1,"name":"abc1"}
      * {"id":2,"name":"abc2"}
      * {"id":3,"name":"abc3"}
      */
    val fileName = "spark-test-data.json"
    val path = getClass.getResource("/" + fileName).getPath

    spark.catalog.createTable("df", path, "json")
      .show(false)

    /**
      * +---+----+
      * |id |name|
      * +---+----+
      * |1  |abc1|
      * |2  |abc2|
      * |3  |abc3|
      * +---+----+
      */
    // Collect only statistics that do not require scanning the whole table (that is, size in bytes).
    spark.sql("ANALYZE TABLE df COMPUTE STATISTICS NOSCAN")
    spark.sql("DESCRIBE EXTENDED df ").filter(col("col_name") === "Statistics").show(false)

    /**
      * +----------+---------+-------+
      * |col_name  |data_type|comment|
      * +----------+---------+-------+
      * |Statistics|68 bytes |       |
      * +----------+---------+-------+
      */
    spark.sql("ANALYZE TABLE df COMPUTE STATISTICS")
    spark.sql("DESCRIBE EXTENDED df ").filter(col("col_name") === "Statistics").show(false)

    /**
      * +----------+----------------+-------+
      * |col_name  |data_type       |comment|
      * +----------+----------------+-------+
      * |Statistics|68 bytes, 3 rows|       |
      * +----------+----------------+-------+
      */
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. I do not have access to the PySpark. We only run SparkSQL queries in Sql Workbench. In workbench we access the tables thru a Glue catalog connected by a Hive driver.

Comment: All these queries are spark sql queries only.

Comment: However, when I executed  your statements in sql-workbench, it returned the error: `org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not create a Path from an empty string;`  and for the describe statement: `No object named extended mytesttable found!`

Comment: Can your spark sql queries there? I guess no

Comment: Yes.. we run spark sql queries on those Glue catalog tables thru Sql Workbench which uses a hive jdbc connector.

Comment: Run `analyze table <table-name> compute statistics`, please let me know the outcome

Comment: For the `ANALYZE` statement it errored out as : `org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not create a Path from an empty string`. And for the `DESCRIBE EXTENDED` statement it errors also: `No object named extended mytesttable found!`

Comment: Please have a look at this spark sql doc-https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/language-manual/analyze-table.html